# Wordpress Plugin -> Is there an API call to get what the URL will be of an article?

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a wordpress plugin and I have a hook for everytime the publisher publishes an article. I'm sending some of that data to a server. Is there an API in wordpress I can call that will tell me what the URL of the article would be?

for example....
I'll know what the article ID is and can craft a URL like
http://thedomain.com/?p=1234
however that won't be the URL that the users sees, it would be more like http://thedomain.com/news/this-is-an-article

Is there a way in wordpress to get the final URL?

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. `$link = get_permalink(1234);`

Comment: Do you have the permalink feature enabled and configured properly? Are you giving it a post ID that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: worked, didn't have permalink set right on my local machine, thanks :)